# spring-amqp compatibility with ibm jvm

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, ibm-jvm, x509trustmanager

I'm using `spring-amqp` with IBM JVM and when initializing a rabbit template to work with ssl it uses `sunx509`, but IBM JVM is not compatible with the algorithm so I get:

```java
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SunX509 KeyManagerFactory not available
```

I'm not sure how to override the use of `sunx509` since the used algorithm is defined in spring-amqp source code

I initialize rabbitmq configuration as shown below
Any suggestions?

Thanks

```java
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);

        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show your connection factory configuration.

Bottom line is you need to wire up/configure the `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory` yourself instead of using Spring's `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean`

It is, indeed hard-coded to `SunX509`; we should make it configurable. Please open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues).